# How to add a pid_t to a string in c

Tags: c, arrays, char, fork, pid

I am experienced in Java but I am **very** new to C. I am writing this on Ubuntu.
Say I have:

```
char *msg1[1028];
pid_t cpid;
cpid = fork();

msg1[1] = " is the child's process id.";
```

How can I concatenate msg1[1] in such a way that when I call:

```
printf("Message: %s", msg1[1]);
```

The process id will be displayed in front of " is the child's process id."?

I want to store the whole string in `msg1[1]`. My ultimate goal isn't just to print it.

Comment: Please format code using the "format code" toolbar button. I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy solution:

```
printf("Message: %jd is the child's process id.", (intmax_t)cpid);
```

Not so easy, but also not too complicated solution: use the (non-portable) `asprintf` function:

```
asprintf(&msg[1], "%jd is the child's process id.", (intmax_t)cpid);
// check if msg[1] is not NULL, handle error if it is
```

If your platform doesn't have `asprintf`, you can use `snprintf`:

```
const size_t MSGLEN = sizeof(" is the child's process id.") + 10; // arbitrary
msg[1] = malloc(MSGLEN);
// handle error if msg[1] == NULL
if (snprintf(msg[1], MSGLEN, "%jd is the child's process id.", (intmax_t)cpid)
  > MSGLEN)
    // not enough space to hold the PID; unlikely, but possible,
    // so handle the error
```

or define `asprintf` in terms of `snprintf`. It's not very hard, but you have to understand varargs. `asprintf` is *very* useful to have and it should have been in the C standard library ages ago.

**EDIT**: I originally advised casting to `long`, but this isn't correct since POSIX doesn't guarantee that a `pid_t` value fits in a `long`. Use an `intmax_t` instead (include `<stdint.h>` to get access to that type).

Comment: I want to store it in msg1[1], my ultimate goal isn't just to print it.

Comment: Great hey thanks man! Sorry if this was a dumb question. You're awesome!

Comment: What does POSIX etc. say about the size of `pid_t`?  Is it guaranteed to fit in a long?

Comment: @asveikau: good point, it actually doesn't. The only safe option would actually to cast it to an `intmax_t`. Will add this to the answer.

Comment: `sizeof("string")` actually _will_ take into account the nul-terminator, so (aside from the arbitrary 10) `MSGLEN` is correct as-is.